# HTML Textarea will not allow me to type in it when added to DOM after DOM loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have a strange issue I have never had before where I have an HTML Textarea element on the page that is added to the DOM after DOM loaded from within my JavaScript application.

The issue is that I cannot get my cursor to go into type/select mode inside the textarea.

It acts almost as if there is a clear div on top of it that is blocking my cursor access to the textarea!

Inspecting in Chrome Dev tools shows nothing on top of my textarea though so I am truly lost to the cause and solution to this issue.

I created a mockup demo here to show the problem http://bit.ly/1K74vkH
On that page if you click the card in the last 4th column to the right of the kanban boards it will open a modal window.  In the modal window you can then click on the **Reject & Move to Pending Validation** button which open another modal on top of everything with the textarea which does not allow text entry.

So that makes me think it might be related to this all being added to the DOM after DOM loaded

My app has Modal windows which open order database records into them.  There are several different modal windows that get built so that is why the content is generated after DOM loaded.  The content created is determined on the type of order item clicked on.

This image below shows my textarea in my app.  I have the textarea selected in Chrome Dev tools so you can see it doesn't show anything covering it up and you can see the CSS settings on it.

Also beside not being able to get into type mode in the textarea, it also does not allow me to select existing text.  The existing text is just test text I set manually from where I put in the textarea code.

Does anyone have any idea why I can't select and gain access to type in the textarea?

Tested in the big 3 browsers, all have same issue!

[image]

---

```
/*
 * jQuery Confirmation Dialog Popup/Modal Window for Deletion approvals and other
 *  similar user actions that require user approval.  This is to replace the browsers
 *  default Dialog confirmation windows.
 *  http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/
 */ (function($) {
     $.confirm = function(params) {
         if ($('#confirmOverlay').length) {
             // A confirm is already shown on the page:
             return false;
         }

         var buttonHTML = '';
         $.each(params.buttons, function(name, obj) {

             // Generating the markup for the buttons:
             buttonHTML += '<a href="#" class="button ' + obj['class'] + '">' + name + '</a>';
             if (!obj.action) {
                 obj.action = function() {};
             }
         });

         var markup = ['<div id="confirmOverlay">', '<div id="confirmBox">', '<h1>', params.title, '</h1>', '<p>', params.message, '</p>', '<div id="confirmButtons">',
                       buttonHTML, '</div></div></div>'].join('');

         $(markup).hide().appendTo('body').fadeIn();

         var buttons = $('#confirmBox .button'),
             i = 0;

         $.each(params.buttons, function(name, obj) {
             buttons.eq(i++).click(function() {

                 // Calling the action attribute when a
                 // click occurs, and hiding the confirm.

                 obj.action();
                 $.confirm.hide();
                 return false;
             });
         });
     }
     $.confirm.hide = function() {
         $('#confirmOverlay').fadeOut(function() {
             $(this).remove();
         });
     }
 })(jQuery);





$(document).on('click', '#btn-reject-move-to-DraftingStage1', function(e) {

    console.log('info', 'ID:btn-reject-move-to-DraftingStage1 clicked on');

    // Show a confirmation Dialog to save new order status or reject and move order back to previous column
    $.confirm({
        'title': 'Reject & Move Back to Drafting Stage 1?',
        'message': 'You are about to update this order item Status to : Drafting Stage 1. <br />Do you wish to Continue?<br><textarea id="comment-reject-2-drafting-stage-1">test</textarea>',
        'buttons': {
            'Yes, Reject & Move Back to Drafting Stage 1': {
                'class': 'blue',
                'action': function() {

                    var commentText = $('#comment-reject-2-drafting-stage-1').val();
                    alert('commentText = '+commentText);

                    // make AJAX request to update order record status

                }
            },
            'Cancel': {
                'class': 'gray',
                'action': function() {
                    // need to move the order card back to its previous status column somehow!
                    //$(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');

                }
            }
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents default
    return false;
});
```

---

**UPDATED DEMO**

To show the real issue which is very rare I had to come up with a live demo so here it is: http://bit.ly/1K74vkH

1. click the card in the last 4th column of the kanban boards
2. In the modal that opens.  Click on the **Reject & Move to Pending Validation** button
3. A 2nd modal opens on top of the first modal which has a textarea filed.  This textarea does not allow any text entry or even focus!

Comment: It works for me on Chrome and Firefox, didn't test IE.

Comment: works for me in IE 11 as well. your commentText should be `var commentText = $('#comment-reject-2-drafting-stage-1').val();` notice the **#** is missing in your code.

Comment: @Sushil good catch on the missing `#` however as mentioned my demo JSFiddle is misleading as it works fine but in my real app it works like the image shows and does not let the user select or type text into the textarea filed for some reason

Comment: @JoshuaCoussard my demo JSFiddle is misleading as it works fine but in my real app it works like the image shows and does not let the user select or type text into the textarea filed for some reason

Comment: Perhaps you're available z-index issues. The textarea might be showing behind a transparent element. Can you reach the textarea by pressing the  tab key?

Comment: yes. that could be the case.

Comment: Since a working fiddle isn't much use in diagnosing your issue, do you have a site we can look at that actually *has* the problem?

Comment: @Sushil I have tried all the usual things like that and it's not a hidden div or element covering with hieght `z-index` and basically nothing else you would expect it to be.  That is what makes it such a weird issue.  Worse is its on a private app behind a login for my boss's timeclock system so I cant share a live link. I am going to try and reproduce a better demo for a public version though

Comment: yeah it would be great if you can get us a public link to test with otherwise it is very difficult for us to figure out whats causing the issue.

Comment: @Sushil I got a public demo setup.  I removed majority of the unused page items to simplify things and also removed over a 500 order records so there is just 7 on the page now to simplify for test.  Also removed about 10 board/columns in our kanban style boards. http://bit.ly/1K74vkH if you go to the 4th/last column board and click "View Order Item" on the last item if opens a modal with the correct version that will show the textarea. After opening modal click "Reject & Move to Pending Validation" button....continue

Comment: ...continued from last msg.... It then shows another modal with the textarea that will not let you type text into it

Comment: @j08691 I built a test page which has the problem http://bit.ly/1K74vkH instructions to see it are posted at the bottom of my question above. thanks

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Ftimeclock.neonandmore.com%2Flabs%2Ftextareabug.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears to be with this div:

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="orderModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="orderModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;"><!--Modal stuff goes here--></div>
```

It appears that the tabindex property on the bootstrap modal div is causing the issue where the textarea cannot be edited when the bootstrap modal is opened. The tabindex property appears to come from the bootstrap boilerplate for their modal implementation, however, after much experimentation in Chrome and IE, I have discovered that removing the tabindex property will allow for editing of the textarea element in the outer modal window.

Your div should look like this as a result:

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="orderModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="orderModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;"><!--Modal stuff goes here--></div>
```

I have images below for your reference.

[image: The div in question]

[image: The tabindex property removed]

[image: Success!]

Comment: awesome work thanks so much I will test tomorrow and select answer...i never would of thought to try that!

Comment: I'm looking forward to hearing about your results. Please let me know if I can assist you further.

Comment: It worked in my live app...thanks a bunch this has been an issue for a few days now!

Comment: Awesome! I am thrilled to hear that it worked for you! You're quite welcome!

Comment: Thanks @JacobHeater ... You saved me from insanity